# Check Status of the Duplicate Records

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

Lets say we have a table named `record` with 4 fields

```
id    (INT 11 AUTO_INC)

email (VAR 50)

timestamp (INT 11)

status (INT 1)
```

And the table contains following data

[image]

Now we can see that the email address test@xample.com was duplicated 4 times (the record with the lowest timestamp is the original one and all copies after that are duplicates). I can easily count the number of unique records using

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM record
```

I can also easily find out which email address was duplicated how many times using

```
SELECT email, count(id) FROM record GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(id)>1
```

But now the business question is

How many times `STATUS` was 1 on all the Duplicate Records?

For example:

- For test@example.com there was no duplicate record having status 1
- For second@example.com there was 1 duplicate record having status 1
- For third@example.com there was 1 duplicate record having status 1
- For four@example.com there was no duplicate record having status 1
- For five@example.com there were 2 duplicate record having status 1

So the sum of all the numbers is `0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 2 = 4`

Which means there were 4 Duplicate records which had `status = 1` In table

**Question**

**How many Duplicate records have status = 1 ?**

Comment: Consider providing a sqlfiddle (or proper ddls anyway)

Comment: A temporary comment regarding your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18307508/285587 - this thing on () with arrays is just not true, while your answer is technically right.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks, I came to know that since 5.5, `()` notion can be used for accesing array values, hence I deleted my answer and upvoted yours. Thanks again :)

Comment: Have you any evidence on it, beside one unreliable comment?

Comment: That's a very good question, and embarrassing answer is that I considered the comment to be valid without doing any research. Can't seem to find any reference to what I was told there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new solution that works better. It removes the first entry for each email and then counts the rest. It's not easy to read, if possible I would write this in a stored procedure but this works.

```
select sum(status)
  from dude d1
  join (select email, 
               min(ts) as ts 
          from dude 
         group by email) mins 
 using (email)
 where d1.ts != mins.ts;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/379cb/8)

**original answer below**

Your own query to find "which email address was duplicated how many times using"

```
SELECT email, 
       count(id) as duplicates 
  FROM record 
 GROUP BY email 
HAVING COUNT(id)>1
```

can easily be modified to answer "How many Duplicate records have status = 1"

```
SELECT email, 
       count(id) as duplicates_status_sum 
  FROM record 
 GROUP BY email 
 WHERE status = 1 
HAVING COUNT(id)>1
```

Both these queries will answer *including* the original line so it's actually "duplicates including the original one". You can subtract 1 from the sums if the original one always have status 1.

```
SELECT email, 
       count(id) -1 as true_duplicates 
  FROM record 
 GROUP BY email 
HAVING COUNT(id)>1

SELECT email, 
       count(id) -1 as true_duplicates_status_sum 
  FROM record 
 GROUP BY email 
 WHERE status = 1 
HAVING COUNT(id)>1
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, That will give out numbers for each email address separately. I need to grab the number of all such records which meet the criteria, not grouped by email in output. So I want to say 1000 duplicate records have status = 1, not grouped by email since there are thousands of email addresses

Comment: How do we know that if we do count(id)-1 we will be excluding the original record? since we did not specify in this query which one to exclude. This can include the original one and exclude a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong in understanding then your query should be

```
SELECT  `email` , COUNT(  `id` ) AS  `tot` 
FROM  `record` , (
SELECT  `email` AS  `emt` , MIN(  `timestamp` ) AS  `mtm` 
FROM  `record` 
GROUP BY  `email`
) AS  `temp` 
WHERE  `email` =  `emt` 
AND  `timestamp` >  `mtm` 
AND  `status` =1
GROUP BY  `email` 
HAVING COUNT(  `id` ) >=1
```

First we need to get the minimum timestamp and then find duplicate records that are inserted after this timestamp and having status 1.

If you want the total sum then the query is

```
SELECT SUM(  `tot` ) AS  `duplicatesWithStatus1` 
FROM (
SELECT  `email` , COUNT(  `id` ) AS  `tot` 
FROM  `record` , (
SELECT  `email` AS  `emt` , MIN(  `timestamp` ) AS  `mtm` 
FROM  `record` 
GROUP BY  `email`
) AS  `temp` 
WHERE  `email` =  `emt` 
AND  `timestamp` >  `mtm` 
AND  `status` =1
GROUP BY  `email` 
HAVING COUNT(  `id` ) >=1
) AS t
```

Hope this is what you want

Comment: Thanks Suraj, it does not appear to be discarding the Original records, I just need to get the number for duplicates, not for all

Comment: I have edited my answer since you need to exclude the original one so i changed the query from count(id) to count(id)-1

Comment: How do we know that if we do count(id)-1 we will be excluding the original record? since we did not specify in this query which one to exclude. This can include the original one and exclude a duplicate :)

Comment: I think you have to first sort your values in the timestamp table and then do it.

Comment: Sorry @Ø Hanky Panky Ø I had missed the part that you need to exclude the original record. Now modified the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of Duplicate records have status = 1 by

```
select count(*) as Duplicate_Record_Count
from (select *
from record r
where r.status=1
group by r.email,r.status
having count(r.email)>1 ) t1
```

The following query will return the duplicate email with status 1 count and timestamp

```
select  r.email,count(*)-1 as Duplicate_Count,min(r.timestamp) as timestamp
from record r
where r.status=1
group by r.email
having count(r.email)>1
```

Comment: Does this take into account only duplicate records and disregard the original record?

Comment: I have edited my answer,First query will returns only a count and second query will returns you duplicate emails with count